# Qt: read video dimension without creating a video player

Tags: qt, video, qt4, movie

I need to read the dimensions of a given video file (its width and height), without constructing a video player, like Phonon, e.g. My question is which class I should use to get access to this data. I have already tried using QPixmap and QMovie, but niether of them supports *.mov.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pavlo, you can try this:

```
QMediaContent media("myMovie.mov");
QSize resolution = media.canonicalResource().resolution();
```

The code uses [QMediaResource](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2.0-beta1/qmediaresource.html) class from [Qt Mobility](http://qt.nokia.com/products/qt-addons/mobility/) project. I haven't tried it yet and I suppose you need at least a correct backend (plugin that is capable of reading MOV format). I'm giving this answer only from API overview.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will implement it and let you know if it works.

Comment: I did not use Qt Modility, because that would require extra downloads for me and all the other people who I program my code for. I sticked to the default Qt installation and found a different solution, which you can find below, if I are interested. Thank you for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem and I thought I'd share my solution with everybody else.
In the class constructor I initialize the following two variables:

```
media = new Phonon::MediaObject(this);
videoWidget = new Phonon::VideoWidget;
```

I connect a signal of `media` to a slot in my class:

```
connect(media,SIGNAL(stateChanged(Phonon::State,Phonon::State)),
        this,SLOT(videoState(Phonon::State,Phonon::State)));
```

I let the user choose a video file:

```
QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Choose video file"),QDir().homePath(),tr("Video files (*.mov *.mpg *.avi)"));
```

And apply this file to the `media` object:

```
media->setCurrentSource(filename);
Phonon::createPath(media,videoWidget);
```

Because `media` object is already connected to a slot, every change in `media` can be monitored with its help.

```
void VideoModuleDialog::videoState(Phonon::State newState, Phonon::State oldState)
{
    if(newState == Phonon::PlayingState || newState == Phonon::StoppedState)
    {
        width->setText(QString().number(videoWidget->sizeHint().width()));
        height->setText(QString().number(videoWidget->sizeHint().height()));
    }
    if(newState == Phonon::ErrorState)
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("Video file error!"),
                              tr("Video file error: ") + media->errorString(),QMessageBox::Ok);
    }
}
```

I must admit, however, that this code seems to me to be quite slow. Phonon library is used in my program only in one place, and this is here, in a dialog window where user can choose a video clip to embed, and i want the video dimensions to be read from file. It takes some time until this dialog window opens, so I guess, this solution is a bit too harsh for my problem. However, I was not able to find another solution. If there are different opinions as to the subject of this post, I'd be glad to hear them.